# Alias Column name in mutiple case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to retrieve a value for a alias column using case statement.

```
CASE 
    WHEN FieldA = 'TestA' THEN FieldA1
    WHEN FieldB = 'TestB' THEN FieldB1
    ELSE NULL
END AS Alias1
```

But when I try to use this alias to retrievce value for another alias , I am getting an error

```
CASE
    WHEN Alias1 = FieldA1 THEN FieldA0
    WHEN Alias1 = FieldB1 THEN FieldA1
    ELSE NULL
END AS Alias2
```

Error message I get is :

[image]

Can you suggest a way to get rid of the error or any alternative approach which fulfills my requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use column aliases in the same `SELECT` clause. You have two choices:

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT Alias1,
       CASE
            WHEN Alias1 = FieldA1 THEN FieldA0
            WHEN Alias1 = FieldB1 THEN FieldA1
            ELSE NULL
       END AS Alias2 
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
                WHEN FieldA = 'TestA' THEN FieldA1
                WHEN FieldB = 'TestB' THEN FieldB1
                ELSE NULL
           END AS Alias1,
           FieldA1
           FieldB1
    ...)
```

or you can repeat the logic that you used in the first `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN FieldA = 'TestA' THEN FieldA1
            WHEN FieldB = 'TestB' THEN FieldB1
            ELSE NULL
       END AS Alias1,
       CASE 
            WHEN FieldA = 'TestA' THEN FieldA0
            WHEN FieldB = 'TestB' THEN FieldB0
            ELSE NULL
       END AS Alias2
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I now realise that I missed the obvious second solution :)