# select query case, assigning two variables by conditions / criteria

Tags: mysql, variables, filter, case, multiple-columns

I have a situation, where I need a MySQL query that would select a row by two criteria. Say that I have three columns 'ID', 'QTY', ' PRICE'. What would be the correct way to filter by such logic:

```
 IF MIN(QTY) = 0, THEN MIN QTY AS qty //(*and any 'PRICE' value*)//, 
 ELSE SELECT MAX(PRICE) AS prc //(*and any 'QTY' value*)//.
```

I've found that "CASE WHEN" does almost exactly what I need, but the problem I approached is that in such statement only one variable can be defined.
The statement below would be great if it could somehow be reworked to the logic above.

```
CASE WHEN MIN(QTY) = 0 THEN MIN(QTY) ELSE MAX(QTY) END AS qty
```

Comment: you cannot define two variables by using any control function in select clause [plz check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001886/alias-column-name-in-mutiple-case-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have  a query as

```
SELECT MIN(QTY), MAX(QTY) , MAX(PRICE)
from my_table
```

You con use

```
SELECT MIN(QTY), MAX(QTY) , MAX(PRICE), 
    case when MIN(QTY) = 0 THEN MIN(QTY) ELSE   MAX(PRICE) END prc
from my_table
```

or avoiding intermediate columns

```
SELECT  case when MIN(QTY) = 0 THEN MIN(QTY) ELSE   MAX(PRICE) END prc
from my_table
```